# Adding an attribute to a provider after config

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-flow, to upload files with a servlet but as I was securing the servlet I realized I need to pass the token to the headers so It would work and be secure.  The problem is that ng-flow's settings are declared on a provider inside a .config box.  And as I learned the hard way you can't inject stuff on .config because the injections are created after config.

```
angular.module('UploadModule', [ 'ngResource','flow' ,'AuthModule']).config(
                [ 'flowFactoryProvider',function(flowFactoryProvider,$provide) {
                    //AuthService.getKeycloak();

                    flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
                    target : '/ng-flow-java/upload',
                    permanentErrors : [ 500, 501 ],
                    maxChunkRetries : 1,
                    chunkRetryInterval : 5000,
                    simultaneousUploads : 4,
                    progressCallbacksInterval : 1,
                    withCredentials : true,
                    method : "octet",
                    headers : {'Authorization', 'Bearer + ' token}
                };
                flowFactoryProvider.on('catchAll', function(event) {
                    console.log('catchAll', arguments);
                });
                // Can be used with different implementations of Flow.js
                // flowFactoryProvider.factory = fustyFlowFactory;
            } ]);
```

I am really new to angular so I am looking for a way reassemble this code so I can add the token from my user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I don't understand what exactly is the problem but:

Actually **each** angular service `x` has a ***provider function***. This function is a constructor function and will be instanciated by angular and its result is injectable in config blocks with name `xProvider`. This object should have a special `$get` function which is actually the **factory** for the service, meaning that it will be called to get the single instance of the service, when it is injected into some controller, directive, etc for the first time.
So you should think of an angular service as a function like this:

```
function SomeServiceProvider(){
   this.$get = function SomeServiceFactory(){
   }
   this.someConfigurerFunction(){
   }
}
```

which is registered with `provider` API:

```
someModule.provider("someService", SomeServiceProvider);
```

and angular internally will execute something like `new SomeServiceProvider()` and save it and makes in injectable in config blocks under the name of `someServiceProvider`. Further, when you ask for "someService", in a directive, controller, etc, for the first time, the injector will call something like `new someServiceProvider.$get()`, return its result to you and saves it in its registry for further injections.

When you use other higher level angular module APIs, like `factory` or `service` like this:

```
someModule.factory("anotherService", function AnotherServiceFactory(){
    // code for creating service
});
```

the provider function is generated for you with only a `$get` function, so you don't see the provider function, but still there is a provider function for your service like this:

```
function AnotherServiceProvider(){
    this.$get = AnotherServiceFactory;
}
```

and it's used as constructor to instantiate `anotherServiceProvider` which is injectable in config blocks.

You can find out good information about angular services in [angular documentations for $provide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) and [angular documentations for module API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module)

## Side Notes:

- Good services usually come with a provider that enables you to configure service, but if not, you still can intercept the creation of the service with [`decorators`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module) and make service to work as you want.
- The process of instantiating objects like services is not exactly like what I've said here (I mean `new ...`), but it doesn't changes the concepts described here.

Comment: you can't on .config as far as being told and in my test.  Even in your comments it says that it is not injectable in config blocks. I am sorry to ask you, is it possible to change the code I posted to the format you just posted?

Comment: The piece of code you've included is quite valid. You **can** inject service providers into config blocks. Just go and set `FactoryProvider.defaults.headers` to what you want and it should work. I'm gonna edit my answer to demonstrate what's going on.